# Finding the Voltage drop across capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor

[image: Circuit Diagram]

The capacitance on the square with CB, CC, and CD will be:
$$C_{Eq}=C_C+[1/C_B+1/C_D]^{-1}=246.875$$

I used the equation:
$$V_{Eq}=V_A*[C_A/(C_A+C_{Eq})]$$
$$V_C=V_{Eq}$$
$$V_A+V_C=119V$$ so that I could get the value for V_Eq, which came out to 29.9371V; I plugged this value in to the first equation to get V_A and the sum of the two is 119V. This is not accepted as a correct answer, though. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you ignoring CB and CD?

Comment: The voltage that goes across CB and CD will equal the voltage that goes across CC

Comment: talk to your teacher .... you have a misunderstanding about parallel capacitors

Comment: Let me edit the question... I typed it in wrong...

Comment: Alright, so that V_EQ is the voltage drop between the capacitor grouping on the right hand side. This here should be split evenly between the two branches.

Comment: Okay, so a little tip is when you are in doubt to plug it in a circuit simulator and see what it says. You actually had the right equation, but hit the wrong buttons or something. If I do (125u / (125u + 246.875u)) * 119, I get 40V. This is correct according to simulation in LTSpice. 

The other thing to note is that you need to be clear what Va is. If it is the voltage on the left of Ca *with respect to ground*, then it is 119V. That is given. If it's the voltage drop across Ca, then it is Va - Vc = 79V.

Vd = Veq * (Cb / (Cb + Cd)) = 25V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$125\ s\ 75 = 46.875\$

\$46.875\ \parallel\ 200 = 246.875 \$

\$246.875\ s\ 125 = 82.983 \mu F\$

Charge \$Q = \frac {C} {V} \$. Use as needed to get voltages.

You have Source voltage, so you can work out total charge.

Charge in series is the same.  \$Q_T = Q_A = Q_{Eq}\$

Charge in parallel add.  \$Q_{Eq} = Q_C + Q_{BsD}\$

You should be able to work from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a Capacitive Voltage transformer that divides voltages after charging up according to their impedances.

Normally this used for HVAC with a small initial HV cap to divide down to sense a reduced voltage on a larger cap. But in the case of DC it can work the same as long as we neglect leakage resistance in the steady state.

We know that Zc(ω)=1/(jωC) and that a step function ( turning on the Vdc ) contains a continuous spectrum of frequencies from DC all the way up to 1/RsC but since these are ideal Caps with Rs=0, it does not matter how fast they charge up for the steady-state.

So we just can say here that Zc is proportional to 1/C and use that for doing Thevenin Calculations and voltage dividers just like equivalent R's.

**now try again.**